# How can I display a popup 10 seconds after page load?

Tags: javascript, html

Aim: To display the popup 10 seconds after page load, where popup is designed using div id.

HTML:

```
<div class="popupbox" id="signin" style="display: block;">
```

Solutions Tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(goToSecondTab(), 10000);

    function goToSecondTab() {
        window.location.hash = "signin";
    }
</script>
```

Timer didn't work, but when load the page url was added with `#signin`.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to display a popup after what? Is 5 seconds or 10 seconds? What code do you use to display the popup?

Comment: @EvertonLenger I want to display popup after 10 seconds as already mentioned. Also I mentioned the java script that i tried.

Comment: But do you mean 10 seconds after page load? You are saying 5 seconds in your title.

Comment: Yes 10 Seconds after load. Sorry for the typo in the title (updated the title with correct information)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('a.fancybox[href="#signin"').trigger('click');
}, 1000 * 10);
```

will most likely fix your issue...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the correct function, but in a incorrect way.

You should pass a function to `setTimeout`, but without parentheses. When you use parentheses, you are saying to execute that function right away.

Try out this code and see if it helps:

```
setTimeout(goToSecondTab, 10000);
```

Comment: Timer is working now but did not get the popup. You can check the link for testing purpose : [link](http://www.webstreaksprojects.com/dynamic/studplex_testing/)

Comment: there is no popup relevant in the code you posted, this answer correctly fixes the timeout issue. your popup binding code is probably broken